# Complex exponential only values 1 in $n\pi i $

Tags: complex-analysis

Ok, this seems easy but I have been thinking about it and can't seem to quite convince myself.

lets define $e^z$ to the unique solution to $y'=y\,$ with $\,y(0)=1$ as condition. (Picard)

This whole problem started because I wanted to find the zeros of the complex sine function. The problem then derives into proving that the solutions to $e^z=1$ are of the form $n\pi i $

So, here's what I thought, let's reduce the problem into finding the zeros of $e^z-1$ in a circle of center 0 and radius $2\pi$, one should suppose you have three zeros, $0, \pi i \, $ and $-\pi i$.

$e^z$ is analytic by definition, so the zeros of $e^z-1$ are isolated, so one must guess there exist a biggest circle of center $0$ where $e^z-1$ is one-to-one. How do I prove is of radius $\pi$?

Another thing I thought is finding the zeros using the line integral $\int_{\mid z \mid = 2\pi i} \frac{e^z}{e^z-1}dz$ which will give me the amount of zeros counting their multiplicities (which are clearly 1). But this line integral is pretty much impossible to calculate.

So, I'm stuck and can't seem to find a solution using the definition of $e^z$ given above.

Comment: This is extremely unclear. First of all, the values of $z$ for which we have $e^z=1$ are of the form $z=2n\pi i$, not $n\pi i$. Also, your contour does not much much sense since you have a modulus that is equal a complex number.

Comment: Also, $|z|$ is never equal to $2\pi i,$ since $|z|$ is real, and $2\pi i$ is non-zero and imaginary. But if you correct to $|z|=2\pi,$ your integral path goes through the poles of your integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this without essentially reproducing the usual relationship between the complex exponential and trigonometry. Here's one way to do it: from this definition it's easy to prove that $e^{z+w} = e^z e^w$. For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ this gives $e^{x + yi} = e^x e^{yi}$ where

$$e^{yi} e^{-yi} = e^{yi} \overline{e^{yi}} = 1$$

which gives that $|e^{yi}| = 1$, hence that $|e^{x+yi}| = e^x$. So $|e^z| = 1$ iff $x = 0$, or equivalently iff $z$ is purely imaginary.

Hence $t \mapsto e^{ti}$ is a parameterization of the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ starting from $1$ and satisfying $e^{(t+s)i} = e^{ti} e^{si}$. It follows by continuity that the kernel $\{ t : e^{ti} = 1 \}$ is a closed subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, hence (and this is a nice exercise) is either discrete or all of $\mathbb{R}$; the latter would imply that $e^{ti} = 1$ for all real $t$ which is not consistent with $e^z$ being holomorphic, so

$$\{ t : e^{ti} = 1 \} = \tau \mathbb{Z}$$

for some positive real $\tau$, the smallest positive real satisfying $e^{\tau i} = 1$. $\tau$ can be calculated by calculating that $e^{ti}$ parameterizes the unit circle with unit velocity (this boils down to $\frac{d}{dt} e^{ti} = i e^{ti}$, which gives $| \frac{d}{dt} e^{ti} | = 1$), implying that $\rho$ is equal to the arc length of the unit circle, so $\tau = 2 \pi$.

Comment: That was the way. Thank you, it was pretty straight forward